# Алгоритм удаления битых пикселей из букв

Tags: алгоритм, java, c++

Добрый день.

Есть вот такие картинки:

http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/09/12/42c/58d/6262f90e63c4b76fdeb27a6dd1d18b336663d92f.jpg

Как видно, черным цветом изображены буквы, но на них много битых пикселей.
Нужен алгоритм, как можно уменьшить число битых пикселей до минимума, закрасив букву в черный цвет.

Comment: капча бота делаете?))

Comment: В общем случае задача очень серьезная.
Если все картинки "примерно" такие, стоит взять какую-нибудь готовую классифицирующую нейронную сеть, обучить ее классифицировать буквы по таким картинкам и так "распознавать" текст. Если речь идет именно о закрашивании, то алгоритм будет очень сложным, надо на основании картинки выбрать кластеры с ограничением по размеру сверху, и затем реверсировать их цвет (черные сделать белыми, белые черными).

Comment: Не уверен, но можно попробовать сначала применить на изображении этот [aлгоритм][1], а уже после пробовать [замыкание][2], вдруг что путное выйдет.

[1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_histogram_thresholding
[2]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Какую готовую классифицирующую нейронную сеть посоветуете?

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать применить алгоритм Тана-Триггса (Tan-Triggs). В OpenCV я встречал его использование для снижения вариативности освещённости при распознавании лиц, но и в обозначенной задаче он, на мой взгляд, может помочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Символы получаются относительно чистыми, области их начертания практически целыми, что значительно снижает сложность дальнейшей обработки, которая в том же OpenCV сведётся к достаточно простым операциям.

Сам алгоритм довольно быстрый и не требует какого-либо обучения:

```
Mat tan_triggs_preprocessing(InputArray src
    , float alpha = 0.1, float tau = 10.0, float gamma = 0.2
    , int sigma0 = 1, int sigma1 = 2) {

    Mat X = src.getMat();
    X.convertTo(X, CV_32FC1);

    Mat I;
    pow(X, gamma, I);

    // Calculate the DOG Image:
    {
        Mat gaussian0, gaussian1;

        // Kernel Size:
        int kernel_sz0 = (3*sigma0);
        int kernel_sz1 = (3*sigma1);

        // Make them odd for OpenCV:
        kernel_sz0 += ((kernel_sz0 % 2) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        kernel_sz1 += ((kernel_sz1 % 2) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        GaussianBlur(I, gaussian0, Size(kernel_sz0,kernel_sz0)
            , sigma0, sigma0, BORDER_CONSTANT);
        GaussianBlur(I, gaussian1, Size(kernel_sz1,kernel_sz1)
            , sigma1, sigma1, BORDER_CONSTANT);
        subtract(gaussian0, gaussian1, I);
    }

    {
        double meanI = 0.0;
        {
            Mat tmp;
            pow(abs(I), alpha, tmp);
            meanI = mean(tmp).val[0];

        }

        I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);
    }

    {
        double meanI = 0.0;
        {
            Mat tmp;
            pow(min(abs(I), tau), alpha, tmp);
            meanI = mean(tmp).val[0];
        }

        I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);
    }

    // Squash into the tanh:
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < I.rows; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < I.cols; c++) {
                I.at<float>(r,c) = tanh(I.at<float>(r,c) / tau);
            }
        }
        I = tau * I;
    }

    return I;
}
```

Использовать просто:

```
Mat src_mat = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat dst_mat = tan_triggs_preprocessing(src_mat);
normalize(dst_mat, dst_mat, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

Mat res_mat = src_mat - dst_mat;

imshow("TanTriggs Image", res_mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже говорилили - классифицировать сразу. Ищите примеры классификаторов для [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) - база изображений рукописных цифр. С этого примера все начинают познавать классификаторы.

Так же попробуйте бинаризировать изображение, например [методом Оцу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9E%D1%86%D1%83)

Так же пробуйте варианты размытий, например [медианную фильтрацию](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20medianBlur%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ksize%29)